# Connection timed out, EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh

Initially, ssh was working fine. But now says connection times out. The error is: 
ssh: connect to host ec2-18-188-122-135.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
I tried rebooting the instance and stopping and again restarting the instance still didn't work. Please help.
Instance Id:  i-02fc8035a7f00d1be

The security group allows for ssh connection for port 22. I created new instance with the same security group and it works.But I need the original one to work.

Comment: If you stop and start an instance, it might change Public IP address. Double-check that you are trying to connect to the right address.

Comment: Always keep the source IP address of SSH type to my IP (In case you want to access the server from your system.)